# SSDP in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, ssdp

I start wireshark and enterd in the cmd "ping www.ynet.co.il"

I get packet with protocol SSDP (as describe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpwJ7.jpg) in the attach picture)

what is this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are capturing all traffic on your network visible to your capture machine because you have not applied any capture or display filters, and apparently you have *"Simple Service Discovery Protocol"* traffic on your network.

If you want to focus on only the ICMP traffic, either:

- Apply a capture filter of `icmp` using *"Capture -> Options -> Capture filter for selected interfaces: icmp"*, or
- Apply a display filter of `icmp` in the Wireshark display filter area at the top of the Wireshark screen.

The difference between a capture filter and a display filter is that a capture filter limits what traffic is captured, while a display filter limits which packets of those captured are actually displayed.  While `icmp` is both a valid capture filter and display filter, in general this is not the case.  The general syntax is very different and I would suggest familiarizing yourself with them if you haven't done so already.  Some helpful links:

- For specifying capture filters, refer to the [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) man page.
- For specifying display filters, refer to

  - The [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page
  - The Wireshark [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) page